# Send a Json (POST) request and get multiple JSon responses to handle progress counts

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to show a progressing message with counts in the fortmat of in a ASP.NET MVC (5) application,

> Adding users 2 out of 100...

user selects 100 users in the webpage and click "OK" (post) button. I do a Json POST with all 100 accounts to a Controller (Async controller).

Controller goes through a forloop. Upon completion of each cycle in the for loop, I need to get a Json result to my View to show the progressing number (1 out of 100, 2 out of 100 etc). (1 added, 2 added etc.)

Is this possible? What are the recommended approaches?

Also, after completion of adding 100 users I need to get a complete message.

Currently I send json requests per each user (Handle the loop from the client side). But this has some inefficiencies in my context as my server side methods are optimized for bulk user operations.

All what I am asking is that, is there a way to send a Json (POST) request and get multiple JSon responses until I decide when to exit from the client side?

Answer (score 2):

An Ajax request will only get an Ajax response, not many. So you cannot dodirectly what you want to do.

There are several possible ways to achieve what you want:

1. create an additional action in the server that can check the progress, and create a JavaScript to poll the status, using this action, until the operation finishes. Polling consists on checking the server periodically, so you can do it easily with JavaScript's `setInterval`, which runs the specified callback periodically until you cancel it.
2. using SignalR. In this case you can send notifications directly from the server to the browser.
3. A last option would be to send the actions to the server one by one, i.e. make an ajax call with the first operation, and, when you get the response, send the second operation, and so on. You could even send several requests to the server in parallel.

Comment: I prefer to try 2nd option with SignalR.